# Edit and remove index from list c#

Tags: c#, list

So i have recently started to programming and doing a course in c#.
In this specific task you should make a program that stores data from user input into an list and then print it out and so on.

But i am stuck at two specific things. I want to be able to access the index and edit it and also be able to remove the user input by selecting the right index in the list.

```
 static void DisplayMeny()
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        //Meny text
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + dateTime);
        Console.WriteLine("\n \t Loggboken!");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [1] Skriv nytt inlägg i loggboken");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [2] Skriv ut alla loggar");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [3] Sök inlägg i loggboken");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [4] Redigera inlägg i loggboken");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [5] Ta bort inlägg i loggboken");
        Console.WriteLine("\t [6] Avsluta");
        Console.Write("\t Välj:");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string[]> loggBoken = new List<string[]> { };
        string[] inlägg = new string[3]; // Vektor med 3 index
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        bool kör = true;
        while (kör)
        {
            DisplayMeny();

            int val;
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val); //tryparse funktion för menyvalet

            //Switch funktion för meny val 
            switch (val)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    inlägg = new string[3]; //skappar ett nytt inlägg i loggboken

                    //Får skriva in titel till array
                    Console.Write("Skriv titel: ");
                    inlägg[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();

                    //Skriver inlägget till array
                    Console.Write("Skriv in inlägg: ");
                    inlägg[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();

                    //lägger till datum och tid i loggen adderar det till arreyen
                    var tidFörInlägg = Convert.ToString(dateTime);
                    inlägg[2] = tidFörInlägg;
                    Console.Clear();

                    //adderar allt information samlad till listan
                    loggBoken.Add(inlägg);
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tDet du har sparat i loggboken är: ");
                    foreach (string[] item in loggBoken) //for each som skriver ut alla titlar,loggtexter och tid och datum som är sparat i "loggBoken"
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t Titel: {0}" + "\n \t {1}" + "\n \t {2}"
                            ,item[0],item[1],item[2] );
                         }
                    break;
                case 3: //Sökfunktion
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Sök efter titel på loggar: ");
                    string sök = Console.ReadLine();

                    foreach (string[] text in loggBoken) // foreach som söker efter arrayen i loggboken
                    {
                        if (text[0].Contains(sök)) //Om arrayen hittas i Console.Readline så skrivs den ut. Använder en if sats för det
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n" + text[0] + "\n" + text[1] + "\n" + text[2]); 
                        }
                       else //Om "sök" inte hittar något
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sökning misslyckades");
                        }
                    }
                        break;
                case 4:

                    var grejer = loggBoken[0];
                    string search = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < loggBoken.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Index: {0} Titel: {1}", i, loggBoken[i][0]);
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n Skriv in siffran på loggen du vill ändra på: ");
                    if (grejer.Contains(search))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(search);
                    }

                    break;
                case 5:
                    int input;
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
                    for (int i = 0; i < loggBoken.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0} Titel: {1}", i, loggBoken[i][0]);
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n Skriv in siffran på loggen du vill radera: ");
                    loggBoken.Remove(loggBoken[input]);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //Avslutar programmet
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Avslutar loggboken!");
                    kör = false; //kör blir false och programmet stängs ner
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Välj riktigt menyval!"); // Om du skriver in något annat en menyvalen
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

That is what i have done so far but the segments i need help with are these.
If i have 3 index stored it will always just remove index [0].

```
      case 5:
                    //Remove loggs from index
                    int input;
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
                    for (int i = 0; i < loggBoken.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0} Titel: {1}", i, loggBoken[i][0]);
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n Skriv in siffran på loggen du vill radera: ");
                    loggBoken.Remove(loggBoken[input]);
                    break;
```

I dont even know if i am close with this one. But same thing here. User should be able to enter the index and then be able to edit the text written there before.

```
  case 4:
                    // Edit list
                    var grejer = loggBoken[0];
                    string search = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < loggBoken.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Index: {0} Titel: {1}", i, loggBoken[i][0]);
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n Skriv in siffran på loggen du vill ändra på: ");
                    if (grejer.Contains(search))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(search);
                    }
```

I hope you all understand what i want to achieve here. And i will be so grateful for any response. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can first remove the element at the specific index and later insert the new element at that index.

Comment: Alter item: `loggBoken[x] = "newValue";`. Remove item: `loggBoken.RemoveAt[x];`.

Comment: The code will not work.  When deleting items from a list 1, 2,3, 4 when you delete 2 item 3 will become 2; and 4 will become 3. so you end up skipping 3.  So when deleting in a loop always go from end to start like this : for(int i = myList.Length -1;i >= 0;i--){ your code here }